# Is it possible to have the pinned shortcuts indicate that they are running?

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, taskbar, windows-8.1

I have a 3 monitor setup.  I set the app icons to show on the taskbar of the display that it is on.  This part works great.

I have pinned a number of apps.  Let's take Outlook as an example.  It is pinned.  So I open it and while it is on the main monitor, I can plainly see on the taskbar that it is running.  However, when I move the app to a different display...the Outlook taskbar icon now moves to a different monitor and rightly so.  However, on the main monitor, the pinned Outlook icon looks like Outlook is not running.

Is there a way to get even a subtle UI cue that the app is running on a different screen, so that I don't mistakenly keep on opening it?

Comment: Are you using some custom software to extend the taskbar?

Comment: @txtechhelp No, it's built in to Windows.  Right click on the Taskbar and select Properties.  All options are there.

Comment: Just making sure since there's a few of them out there :)

Comment: One thing I did was to simply keep the taskbar on one monitor.

Answer (score 1):

What I do is "force" the taskbar icons to stay open on the main monitor taskbar. This way, if the app is running, the icon will be shown as *running* on both taskbars.

The downside is that the taskbar icon now appears on multiple monitors; I assume you might not want it to be expanded on the main monitor when it is shown on a secondary monitor, but this is nonetheless a visual cue...

[image: Taskbar options]

Comment: It's a good half step, but I was trying to get away from having multiple icons.  Instead I wanted a subtle cue like in Mac OSX.